# find a specific header and insert a row above it and insert some value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a specific header and trying to insert a row above it and insert some value

for example sheet called "System" in (A1:Q1) if its find header as "assignee" in G column,  it should inert a row above it and paste value as " Open with assignee" in G column

in the same way it should check entire G column and if its finds next assignee it should insert a row above it and paste value as " Open with customer " in G column

can anyone help me with vba code

Comment: I think you might want to break down your task to smaller sub-tasks, for which finding the solution here on SO will be straight forward, rather than expecting the full solution to your specific problem here. Smaller tasks that I see in your question are: 1) How to find text in sheet/column using VBA. 2) How to add row above a range 3) How to write in Excel cell using VBA..  Find the solution for these three will give you the building blocks you need to write your entire solution.

Comment: I am looking something like 'Sub column()

Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
Cells(1, 8) = "Open with Infosys"
'Here the first value is Row Value and the second one is column value
'Cells(1, 1) means first row first column
'after above code it should find the next header with with columns assignee and insert a row above it and input value (1,8) = "Open with bank"
End Sub'

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st part of the query (inserting a row above the header):

One thing you could do, if this is just a single sheet, is to name the range in which the headers exist (so, if Row 1 is where all the headers are normally, say A1:Q1, then name A1:Q1 as HeaderRow or similar). This has the advantage that, when you insert rows you don't have to put in any code to reassign the header row. Now, rather than looking through an entire sheet, you're focusing your search on a single defined range.

Once this is done, simply use `For Each [cell] in [range].Cells` to iterate through each cell, and determine if the cell's contents are what you're looking for. If so, you can insert the row above, and populate the cell that is `[cell].Row - 1` from your target cell.

It'd look something like this:

```
Dim InternalCell as Range, myNamedRange as Range
Dim SearchTerm as String
SearchTerm = "assignee"
Set myNamedRange.Cells = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("System").Range("HeaderRows")

For Each InternalCell In myNamedRange.Cells
If InternalCell.Value = SearchTerm Then
myNamedRange.Insert Shift:=xlDown
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("System").cells(MyNamedRange.Row - 1, InternalCell.Column).Value = "Open with assignee"
End If
Next InternalCell
```